# Android Twitter Connectivity?

Tags: android, twitter

Which is the best Twitter connectivity **Library** for Android?. And any examples available?

Comment: Twitter4j may be useful to you: [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for the Reference. I added it in to my Project, is there any example for how to login with Twitter4j and update status?

Comment: Have a look at e.g. the code samples provided on the twitter4j page or at https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/tree/v065 for an open source client using that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Share Content Use SocialAuth Android Library. The library also help you to integrate faceebook, twitter and myspace.

Here is link.

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's in your case but if you only need to share content on twitter a Library is not needed. Use intent.