# Twitter4J on android set up Twitter object

Tags: android, twitter4j

I decided to try Twitter4J but it seems the documentation is kind of mixed up. So I couldn't find an example with the flow of the auth process in order to tweet "hello world".

Firstable, I already set up the twitter app. The thing is the Callback URL, I don't know what  is that. What is the callback URL, what do I put in there. Does that URL needs to point to some website that I have to create? I need a complete explanation on this callback url thing

Also, does the user authenticate only via a web browser, or is it done with the twitter app as in facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstable, I already set up the twitter app. The thing is the Callback
>   URL, I don't know what is that. What is the callback URL, what do I
>   put in there. Does that URL needs to point to some website that I have
>   to create? I need a complete explanation on this callback url thing

The callback URL is used after the user has been successfully authenticated and he's given a valid OAuth access token. It can be any well-formed URL, not necessarily an existing one: usually this URL is intercepted in the web browser by the dev, who then can parse the given token and use the twitter APIs as an authenticated user.

> Also, does the user authenticate only via a web browser, or is it done
>   with the twitter app as in facebook?

TwitterJ is a generic Java library, so you have to create your own Android-specific stuff in order to authenticate yourself. For instance you can put a `WebView` in your custom `Activity` and then handle the authentication stuff all by yourself.

Comment: I see. Then, what URL Callback should I use? since it does not need to exist, could I put "twitter_callback_url" as the Callback URL field on the twitter app and on the android app  or should it need some format like "http://twitter_callback_url"  or "http://twitter_callback_url.com"  ?

Comment: I've seen some examples where they put something like `<data android:scheme="this_example">`  on the manifest, and then they use `String callbackurl = "this_example:///";` will it work? or should i go with `http://fictionalurl.com`  on the `<data>` and `String` ?

Comment: Never used myself, but AFAICT using a custom android scheme as url callback would result in calling back your Activity, then you will have to handle the generated Intent accordingly to complete the Twitter authentication process. Personally I usually like better  to use `http://fictionalurl.com` and to handle all this stuff without going "out of scope" with spanning an Intent after a custom scheme detection. BTW it's all up to you, because both options will work.

Answer (score 1):

Callback URL tells where to send information when it is requested by the developer's application.

I integrated socialauth-android sdk to integrate twitter in my application after reading this post
[Android Twitter Connectivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967625/android-twitter-connectivity/11240243#11240243)

The library is available at http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/